# Use a table for a loop in windows batch

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I have a problem to use a table in a `for` loop in a batch file.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
SET /P input1=Nombre de camion : 
set nombreDeCamion=%input1%

for /l %%f in (1,1,%nombreDeCamion%) DO (
    set index=%%f
    SET /P input=Entrer le no du camion: 
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set tableauNoCamion[%index%]=!input!
    echo You entered !tableauNoCamion[%index%]!
    endlocal
)

for %%n in (%tableauNoCamion%) DO (
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo %%n
    endlocal
)
pause
```

In the second loop, I wanted to see if my table was well populated.

I liked to populate my table called `tableauDeCamion` with the data entered by the user with the input. After that, I want to use this table to eventually rename some files.
I already tried this for `/r %%f in (*.jpg) DO` to pass over all the JPG files and it worked well. How can I use the table `tableauDeCamion` in that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a major problem with

```
set tableauNoCamion[%index%]=!input!
echo You entered !tableauNoCamion[%index%]!
```

as `%index%` will be evaluated with the contents of `index` at the time the `for ...%%f` was **parsed**

Don't bother with `index` at all; use

```
set tableauNoCamion[%%f]=!input!
echo You entered !tableauNoCamion[%%f]!
```

As for the second loop, you could use

```
set tableauNoCamion
```

or

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set tableauNoCamion') do echo %%a
```

or

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%a in (1,1,%nombreDeCamion%) do echo !tableauNoCamion[%%a]!
endlocal
```

(all air code - untested)

and there are others - depending on what report you want.

As for whatever you want to do with the `*.jpg` or the not-`*.jpg` files - it's a mystery to me...

---

Ah, yes - the problem is that any changes made to the environment after a `setlocal` are undone when the matching `endlocal` is reached.

Hee's a revision...

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /P input1=Nombre de camion : 
set nombreDeCamion=%input1%

for /l %%f in (1,1,%nombreDeCamion%) DO (
    set index=%%f
    SET /P input=Entrer le no du camion: 
    set tableauNoCamion[%%f]=!input!
    echo You entered !tableauNoCamion[%%f]!
)
echo===============
SET tableaunocamion
echo===============

for /L %%a in (1,1,%nombreDeCamion%) do echo !tableauNoCamion[%%a]! 
echo===============

for /f "tokens=2,3delims=[]=" %%a in ('SET tableaunocamion') do echo %%a. %%b

GOTO :EOF
```

Note: I code for running within a `cmd` session. If you run from a "shortcut" you'd need to insert a `pause` strategically.

Here's a sample result: (entering 4,11,22,33,44)

```
Nombre de camion : Entrer le no du camion: You entered 11
Entrer le no du camion: You entered 22
Entrer le no du camion: You entered 33
Entrer le no du camion: You entered 44
==============
tableauNoCamion[1]=11
tableauNoCamion[2]=22
tableauNoCamion[3]=33
tableauNoCamion[4]=44
==============
11 
22 
33 
44 
==============
1. 11
2. 22
3. 33
4. 44
```

Comment: Hi Magoo, 
I tried your solutions for the second loop but unfortunately, the first two gave me this error. The environment variable tableauNoCamion is not define.
the third one gave me the error Echo command is deactivated